# Is it possible to update a Partial view / <div> with AJAX helper Method when Java Script is disabled

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I know that a very similar question was posted and ansered:
[How to gracefully handle AJAX PartialView update when Javascript is disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21934536/how-to-gracefully-handle-ajax-partialview-update-when-javascript-is-disabled)

But that solution isnt satisfying me.

Is it possible, to update a  Element with the Ajax Helper Method when Java Script is disabled, that it will show a partial view in the same page and not in an extra tab?

I want that the  Tag in the Index View is updated with a partial View (_Details), when I click on a AJAX ActionLink.
With the PView 1 Method, I get the same result with JS enabled and disabled. But i dont linke the PView 1 solution (as suggested in the similar question), because this makes the Partial View Class useless. Why would i need it when i reload the hole page anyway.
I would prefer a solution similar to PView 2. But there the Partial View is opened in a new Tab when JS is disabled.

My very simplified code so far:

HomeController Class

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var obj_str = new SimpleString { astr = "Nothing Yet" };
        return View(obj_str);
    }

    public ActionResult PView1()
    {
        string str_posted = "String of PView 1";
        var obj_str = new SimpleString {astr = str_posted};

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return PartialView("_Details", obj_str);
        }else
        {
            return View("Index", obj_str);
        }
    }

    public PartialViewResult PView2()
    {
        var obj_str = new SimpleString {astr = "String of PView 2"};
        return PartialView("_Details", obj_str);
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
<h2>AJAX Actionlink Index</h2>
@Ajax.ActionLink("Click me for PView 1", "PView1", new AjaxOptions
{
    UpdateTargetId = "partv",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    HttpMethod = "GET"
})

@Ajax.ActionLink("Click me for PView 2", "PView2", "Home", new AjaxOptions
{
    UpdateTargetId = "partv",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    HttpMethod = "GET"
})

<h3>Partial View here!</h3>                     
<div id="partv">
    <p>@Model.astr</p>
</div>
```

_Details.cshtml (the Partial View)

```
@model MVCPartialViewTest.Models.SimpleString
<p>This is from the Partial View cshtml</p>
<p>@Model.astr</p>
```

SimpleString Class (the Model)

```
public class SimpleString
{
    public string astr { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: with ajax, you have obviously the benefit of discrete updates that don't cycle the entire http pipeleine. however, what you're asking is only possible via cycling the entire pipeline. in some ways, think back to how POST was handled prior to ajax being ubiquitious and you have your solution. in essence, you'll need to `re-post` the source view PLUS the additional partial details when not using ajax. it's just not possible to target fragment updates otherwise.

Comment: You answered your own question when you said "AJAX" (a technology that relies on JavaScript) and "JavaScript is disabled". If JavaScript is disabled, anything that relies on JavaScript obviously is out of the question.